# What kind of filter should be used to find the objects in this image?

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I have 3d image of tissue containing nuclei. There are some regions in the image where nuclei are very dense and some are noisy. So, what kind of filters should I choose to remove the noise and find the exact location of nuclei. Here is the image.

[image]

I am novice to image processing. So, any help would be appreciable.

Comment: All nuclei have approximately the same size. Therefore some kind of bandpass filter should be helpful.

Comment: This question is off-topic here on stackoverflow, as it is not a programming question. Please ask on the [image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc/) where it's all about image analysis.

Comment: If you want to remove the noise and, keep the edges and information you can use Adaptive filters.